# Ettercap : Is it possible to use redirect all HTTP website with DNS Spoof?

Tags: spoofing, spoof, ettercap

As my title says, I'm trying to use Ettercap for DNS Spoofing. I put the name of the website that I want to redirect in etter.dns and it works well. But now I would like to redirect all HTTP websites.

Do you know if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

First, DNS is about mapping name to IP address. So, you just cannot only spoof "HTTP" which generally mean TCP/80 . All connections to any port will be connected to the IP address.

Second, DNS spoof is just playing with how stateless UDP protocol is. DNS is about query "name" and reply "address". Spoofing is flooding replies to the specific terminal without query. Therefore, the replies need to have a specific name in it. Therefore, no wildcard but you can try to put as many names as you want.